# Pinpoint API returning

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-pinpoint

Trying to set up Postman to send push notifications through AWS.  I've got the notifications going out through the Test Notifications interface to a specific DeviceID in the management console.  But I'm receiving the error message below when attempting to send via Postman.

```
{"message":"Credential should be scoped to correct service: 'mobiletargeting'. "}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you use the **AWS Signature** feature in the Authorization tab?
If so, set the **Service Name** to *mobiletargeting* (that's an advanced setting of the authentication).
Accept and Content-Type set to application/json

Comment: Actually got it working this morning and that was the solution!  It was set to 'execute-api'.